Jenkins: Groovy find function doesn't assign matches in capturing groups to parameters
I am trying to get the account name of the pipeline which is running based on the folder it is running inside Jenkins.
To do that I am using a regex filter in the find() function of Groovy which takes in a closure argument, whose parameters are assigned values based on the match and capturing groups of the regex as documented here.
But when I try to run it in my pipeline from a shared library method, the capturing groups are not getting assigned to parameters as expected.
This is the code
def call(){
  def jobName = env.JOB_NAME
  // returns the first capturing group of regex as account name
  jobName.find(~/([A-Za-z]+)\-Pipelines/) { match, account ->
    return account.toLowerCase()
  }
}

The job name is of the pattern somepath/AccountName-Pipelines/pipeline-name
When I run I get null returned and the toLowerCase method fails. On printing the match parameter's value I see the String array with the complete match and the capturing group as expected.
However the same code when run inside Jenkins Script Console works fine and the account parameter is assigned with the capturing group value as expected.
What is the reason for this discrepancy within Jenkins itself?

Have you tried env.JOB_NAME.toString() or checked what type it is?

@cfrick It is already of type java.lang.String and adding the toString() doesn't change anything. If it had been of a different type I don't think the find() function would have worked in the first place.
This is so weird that it is able to do the match and get the right capturing group but simply not make the closure work properly.
